# Should I user meteor packages or copy js files?

Tags: javascript, meteor, atmosphere.js

There are many js libraries built by enthusiasts that are incredible. And some of them have found a place in [atmospherejs](http://atmospherejs.com) (some of them migrated not by their autor). Should I use the original ones (js files) or add the meteor packages that are the meteor version of these libraries?
For example:

Sweet alert:

[Meteor version](https://atmospherejs.com/kevohagan/sweetalert) by someone else

[Original version](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) by ther author

Answer (score 1):

You can do both, if you take a look in usage you will find first one (meteor one) you need meteor to install it:

## Usage

```
meteor add kevohagan:sweetalert
```

---

And second one you have a working plugin installable via `bower` or `npm`

## Usage

**Method 1: Install through bower:**

```
$ bower install sweetalert
```

**Method 2: Install through NPM:**

```
$ npm install sweetalert
```

---

So, if it is not last option, you dont need to get manually any files.

Comment: is there a advantage, disadvantage over using one instead of another? like memory, speed, etc

Comment: My advice will be, work with the tool you feel more comfortable. I didn't work with `meteor` but seems similar to `npm` and `bower`, they will give you not only repository handling, but also many other options, I prefer `npm`, but is just a matter of taste and own experience.